# How value passed to this lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying out a sample in ASP.NET MVC 4. He create an extension method for HtmlHelper. Below is the code:

```
public static class PagingHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
        PagingInfo pagingInfo,
        Func<int, string> pageUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
            if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");
            result.Append(tag.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is used by a view as below:

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
```

This is the controller that defines the action method for the view:

```
public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
{
    ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel {
        Products = repository.Products
            .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
        },
        CurrentCategory = category
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Based on the results of the extension method (and using breakpoints), the value of x is the 'page' parameter on the List action method in the controller. How did x get a hold of that? Or how did the value get passed to x? I've mostly used delegates on LINQ when I am working with collections; the value passed as parameter is from the collection (iterated). But I can't seem to grasp this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `Func<int, string> pageUrl` means a function **with one int param** and which **returns string**.

You are calling this function in `for loop` by:

```
tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
```

When you are calling pageUrl it basically calls something like:

```
public String SomeFunction(int x)
{
  return Url.Action("List", new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory });
}
```

So `x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory })` here means anonymous function which just wraps `Url.Action` function

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see the line tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i)). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `PagingHelpers.PageLinks` extension method is using the `Func<int, string>` to generate URLs.

Since the actual generation of the URL is provided by the View, not the extension method, the extension method is just using the mechanism defined in the **view** as the URL generator.

The extension method works like this:

- I loop between 1 and the number of pages
- I generate a link defined by the `Func<int, string>` passed into me

  - (Note I don't care how it works, as long as I give it an `int` and get back a `string`)
- I use that in the `href`.

So look at the view:

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
```

The `Func<int, string>` is saying "When I'm given an int `x`, call this code with it". This way the URL generation is controlled by the view. The extension method is inly interested in the resulting HTML generated by the `Url.Action`.